# Why's 辶 (“move”) the semantic component of 遺 and 述?

Tags: glyph-origin

How do 遺's and  述's meanings appertain to its semantic component 辶?

[image]

*Oxford Chinese Dictionary* (2010) p 689.

[image]

*Op. cit.* p 885.

Comment: Please use [tag:glyph-origin] when asking about character components. “Etymology” means *the origin and relation between morphemes and words*; semantic components are vague meaning categorisations helping to distinguish between different morphemes which sound similar but mean different things, they are not etymological roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes over the many thousands of years, the character has transformed its meaning a lot that you cannot easily make sense it’s semantic component. Instead of using a modern dictionary, consider looking up at an historical one like 說文 or 康熙字典。

述，循也。——《说文》(To follow)
https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E8%BF%B0

遺，離也。——《釋言》(To go away; to leave)
https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E9%81%BA

Both can connect to the action of “walking”, thus the component 辵

Comment: EXcellent explanations and references.